# react cannot set property of props of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component like this

```
import { Component } from 'react'

export default class SearchList extends Component(){
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        const { placeholder } = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="searchList">
                <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder}/>
                <button>Search</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The somewhere I do `<SearchList placeholder="Search Area" />`

Why I got error of cannot set property of props of undefined?

Comment: remove () from  export default class SearchList extends Component()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a react component extending `React.Component` you don't need the extra `()` after `React.Component`

Use this

```
export default class SearchList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        const { placeholder } = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="searchList">
                <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder}/>
                <button>Search</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ouch, what a careless mistake.