# import React, {PropTypes} from 'react' causing Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm following Cory House's *Building Applicaiton with React and Redux in ES6* course on Pluralsight. I have done everything exactly the same as he does in the lecture and don't know why the following error occurs when I create the app layout:

[image: a screenshot of the error occured in the console]

Can anyone give me a hint about the reason this might occur please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react cannot set property of props of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061769/react-cannot-set-property-of-props-of-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write

```
class App extends React.Component
```

not

```
class App extends React.Component()
```